# How do I align the text beside the picture?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

The code is:

```
<main>
    <p>The following decades show the data:</p><br>
    <img src="fiba-1950.jpg"><p>-1950</p>
    <p>1960</p>
</main>
```

The text is under the image, I tried changing the value of `p` but that would also change the upper paragraph. I would like the text to be aligned to the left so that there would be space in between both images. "-"
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can add float property to the image like:

```
<img src="fiba-1950.jpg" style="float: right;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <p>The following decades show the data:</p><br>
  <img src="fiba-1950.jpg"><p>-1950</p>
  <p>1960</p>
</div>
```

That will help you. If you use bootstrap, it will be more easy.